# Refreshing a webpage will not reset HTML table with jQuery activities in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, firefox

Sorry if this question has been asked before.

- I had a simple HTML table and added some hide/unhide features through
  jQuery.
- The table worked fine in Chrome `24.0.1312.52 m` and IE8+.
- However, when I refreshed the webpage in Firefox `15.0.1`, previously
  filled table would not be reset. Has anyone had this experience
  before? Do I need to add something to let jQuery reset the form?

Below is my code and a link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/qpK7Y/). Thanks for any suggestions!

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="id_application">Application:</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <select name="application" id="id_application">
                <option value="">Make a selection</option>
                <option value="a">Aerial</option>
                <option value="b">Ground</option>
                <option value="c">Orchard/Airblast</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="id_boom_height">Boom height:</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <select name="boom_height" id="id_boom_height">
                <option value="">Make a selection</option>
                <option value="1">Low</option>
                <option value="2">High</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="id_orchard_type">Orchard type:</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <select name="orchard_type" id="id_orchard_type">
                <option value="">Make a selection</option>
                <option value="1">Vineyard in leaf</option>
                <option value="2">Orchard or dormant vineyard</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#id_boom_height').closest('tr').hide();
        $('#id_orchard_type').closest('tr').hide();

        $('#id_application').change(function () {
            $('#id_boom_height').closest('tr').hide();
            $('#id_orchard_type').closest('tr').hide();
            if ($(this).val() == "b") {
                $('#id_boom_height').closest('tr').show();
                $('#id_orchard_type').closest('tr').hide();
            } else if ($(this).val() == "a") {
                $('#id_boom_height').closest('tr').hide();
                $('#id_orchard_type').closest('tr').hide();
            } else if ($(this).val() == "c") {
                $('#id_boom_height').closest('tr').hide();
                $('#id_orchard_type').closest('tr').show();

            }
        });
    });
```

#### Update:

Thanks for the help from Hanlet Escaño. I added a reset button to the table and bind it to the page refresh. As a result, when I refresh pages in Firefox, I am able to change the table to its default condition.

#### However, when I click the reset button, the only the form's contents are reset, but the structure of it. Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/godhong/CFbtH/9/). I appreciate if anyone could help out of it. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how your jsfiddle has anything to do with this code brah.

Comment: @HanletEscaño: I consider jsfiddle code as an failed example...

Answer (score 1):

I tried it on the same version of Firefox and I did not get your error. However, I have modified your code a little bit to reset the form when people leave the page. It's a workaround until you figure what's wrong.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="id_application">Application:</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <select name="application" id="id_application">
                <option value="">Make a selection</option>
                <option value="a">Aerial</option>
                <option value="b">Ground</option>
                <option value="c">Orchard/Airblast</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="id_boom_height">Boom height:</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <select name="boom_height" id="id_boom_height">
                <option value="">Make a selection</option>
                <option value="1">Low</option>
                <option value="2">High</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <label for="id_orchard_type">Orchard type:</label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <select name="orchard_type" id="id_orchard_type">
                <option value="">Make a selection</option>
                <option value="1">Vineyard in leaf</option>
                <option value="2">Orchard or dormant vineyard</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="$('#id_application>option:eq(0)').attr('selected', true);  $('#id_application').change();">Try</button>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#id_boom_height').closest('tr').hide();
        $('#id_orchard_type').closest('tr').hide();

        $('#id_application').change(function () {
            $('#id_boom_height').closest('tr').hide();
            $('#id_orchard_type').closest('tr').hide();
            if ($(this).val() == "b") {
                $('#id_boom_height').closest('tr').show();
                $('#id_orchard_type').closest('tr').hide();
            } else if ($(this).val() == "a") {
                $('#id_boom_height').closest('tr').hide();
                $('#id_orchard_type').closest('tr').hide();
            } else if ($(this).val() == "c") {
                $('#id_boom_height').closest('tr').hide();
                $('#id_orchard_type').closest('tr').show();

            }
        });

$(window).bind('beforeunload',function(){
    $('#id_application>option:eq(0)').attr('selected', true);
    $('#id_application').change();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wLnyu/6/

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your code! This firefox issue recently jumped out and I am confused since each explorer has its own rule...

Comment: Please try and see if it works, if not we can find another solution.

Comment: your approach almost worked, which reset the contents not the structure (hide non-called items in Firefox...). Would you mind taking a look at my updates?